# How to efficiently fill a UITextView with streaming content?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have an iOS app which I use to trigger an action. This action produces a lot of text, and I want to show it to the user as it updates. My current method chokes on longer (5k line) output. What can I do to handle this beyond truncating after a few hundred lines?

---

Currently what I do is have the process stream output to a file. Then I take a `FileHandle` on this file, and create a `readabilityHandler` which passes the snippet to my `UIViewController`:

```
stdout_handler = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "my.txt")
stdout_handler?.readabilityHandler = { handle in
    let data = handle.readData(ofLength: 100)
    if let snippet = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        self.delegate?.append_script(text: snippet)
    }
}
```

I have my `UIViewController`, the delegate, take this string and append it to the `UITextView.text`

```
func append_script(text: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.script_output.text == nil {
            self.script_output.text = text
        } else {
            self.script_output.text.append(text)
        }

        let last_line = NSRange(location: self.script_output.text.count - 1, length: 1)
        self.script_output.scrollRangeToVisible(last_line)
    }
}
```

In the simple case, it's good enough; but surely there's a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by *My current method chokes*?